# Get child of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I access the children of a `RecyclerView`? I'm not looking for an `onClickListener`. I am trying to figure out how I can change the background of some `TextViews` in the `RecyclerView`. I have really no idea. Any advice would be appreciated.

Please note: the directly children are vertical `LinearLayout`s which contain `TextView`s.

```
public class MessdatenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessdatenAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ArrayList<MessdatenColumn>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MessdatenColumn>>();


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public LinearLayout llVerticalContainer;
    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        llVerticalContainer = (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.layout_messdaten);
    }
}

public MessdatenAdapter(ArrayList<ArrayList<MessdatenColumn>> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MessdatenAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_messdaten, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ArrayList<MessdatenColumn> terminStringList = list.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.getMyAppCompatActivity());
    holder.llVerticalContainer.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0; i < terminStringList.size();i++){
        TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_messdaten_textview, null);

        if(terminStringList.get(i).getValue().equals("NaN")){
            tv.setText("-");
        } else {
            tv.setText(terminStringList.get(i).getValue());
        }

        if (i == 0) {
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        holder.llVerticalContainer.addView(tv);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the position of the child from the adapter,you can use [LinearLayoutManager.getChildAt(index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#getChildAt(int)) to get the childview.

You can use this from the activity in itself.But be careful that you always query for a position which exists or else you will face an `Incosistency Detected` error.

Once you are done making the change,call [RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged (int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) .

Comment: But if the child is not created / visible it will crash? I want to set the background and textcolor of a textview which is part of the recyclerview childs. Even the ones which are not visible because of the scroll position.

Comment: If the child has been created before,the layoutmanager can access it.If it has not been created yet,then you would have do it via a parameter in your model

Comment: Logically,you cannot make a **change** to an view which has not been drawn yet.You can only **draw** it based on what your model or dataset asks it to be drawn.

Comment: Yes u are right. Thanks. I will place something in my model